# Uppercase a string input from scanner in java

Tags: java, string, uppercase

I am supposed to use the Scanner in Java to receive a 14 char input and have all the letter char output in uppercase format. I've tried entering some of the code I found through Google such as " str.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH); " but it tells me str cannot be resolved and that the locale can't be resolved. When I did a search on here I got results for uppercasing specific char or counting char. I just need the specific line of input to be uppercased.

The following is what I have at the moment. I am using eclipse java neon

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class MemberIDLotz {
    // Everette Lotz
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner string = new Scanner(System.in);

        // We're going to get a 14 char string from a user.
        System.out.println("Please enter in a 14 character long ID");
        String name = string.next();
        str.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);

        string.close();
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.

*Edit: Ok so it is no longer giving me an error message, and yes I had simply copy and pasted the code. However when it prints out its not in upper case format. I put the following right after "String name =...." and deleted the `str.toUppercase()` line:

```
System.out.println(name);
name = name.toUpperCase();`
```

Comment: You don't have a variable `str`. You probably copy pasted this from a sample code. Use `name.toUpperCase()`.

Comment: Re your edit, you are printing it before converting it.

Comment: So if I understand correctly I would put the .toUpperCase and then the string.next() ?

Comment: No, if you understood correctly you wouldn't print something that was supposed to rely on the result of a conversion before doing the conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason you don't uppercase immediately?

```
String name = string.next().toUpperCase()
```

Comment: The assignment is to take input for 14char from someone and then format it. So if they entered Input: X839WS21R4E877 then I have to output it as: Display: X-839 WS21 R4-E87 (7). Teach, also said that if the input is entered in lowercase then it should be output in upper. Unless you mean uppercase it earlier in the code? I'm going to school for programming so I am not exactly "knowledgeable" in this.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't uppercase immediately. That was my point. Your question makes that two steps when it could be one.

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly, by using the code you provided it uppercase's immediately where as if I place the code lower it'd be like a second step. Correct?

Comment: You would read the string as whatever was entered, correct. With this one line you immediately convert the typed string to uppercase. You can do whatever substring parsing logic from there.

Comment: "substring parsing logic" My presumption is that substring would simply be any strings after the initial. However parsing means nothing to me.

Comment: "parsing" == "To break (a string) down into its component parts". `X839WS21R4E877` can be "broken into" or "parsed" to form your required output, by using the `substring(int start, int end)` method in Java

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
name = name.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

or more simply

```
name = name.toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add trim to it if you'd like, it is a working example:

```
String choice;

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
choice = s.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
```