# Print out an array in uppercase Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

So for this program I'm currently creating I have had to store 10 names in an array, which is simple enough, then print out that array with the 10 names displayed in uppercase, which is the part I'm currently stuck on. I've been told that using a for or for each loop will be able to achieve this.

This is the code I currently have:

```
package uploadTask8_uppercaseArrays;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class uppercaseArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // creates array that will store the 10 names
        String[] names10 = new String[10];

        System.out.println("Please enter the ten names: \n1: ");
        // create scanner object to get user input
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String firstName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("2: ");
        String secondName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("3: ");
        String thirdName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("4: ");
        String fourthName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("5: ");
        String fifthName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("6: ");
        String sixthName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("7: ");
        String seventhName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("8: ");
        String eigthName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("9: ");
        String ninthName = userInput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("10: ");
        String tenthName = userInput.nextLine();
        userInput.close();

        // assigns user input to each element in the array
        names10[0] = firstName;
        names10[1] = secondName;
        names10[2] = thirdName;
        names10[3] = fourthName;
        names10[4] = fifthName;
        names10[5] = sixthName;
        names10[6] = seventhName;
        names10[7] = eigthName;
        names10[8] = ninthName;
        names10[9] = tenthName;

        // prints out the array in lowercase
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names10));
        // prints out the array in uppercase



    }

}
```

I've had a look at some other code,  but can't actually work out the code for the for or for each loop that changes the array into uppercase. Does anyone know how this would work?

Comment: What do you need all those intermediate variables for? You can do `names10[0] = userinput....` directly. Also, this way you can just use a loop.

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Did you try `toUpperCase()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uppercase a string input from scanner in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016564/uppercase-a-string-input-from-scanner-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

> can't actually work out the code for the for or for each loop that
>   changes the array into uppercase. Does anyone know how this would
>   work?

You can simply convert your string variables to upper case at the time of storing them in the array.

```
    names10[0] = firstName.toUpperCase();
    names10[1] = secondName.toUpperCase();
    ...
```

Or a more elegant option is to run a loop like following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < names10.length; i++) {
    System.out.println((i + 1) + ": ");
    names10[i] = userInput.nextLine().toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toUpperCase()` to get in upper case.

Your code is too big and not efficient. you should use loop for this. How about making it shorter like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // creates array that will store the 10 names
        String[] names10 = new String[10];

        System.out.println("Please enter the ten names: \n");
        // create scanner object to get user input

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i+": ");
            names10[i-1] = userInput.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        }

        for(int i =1;i<=10;i++)
            System.out.println(names10[i-1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

Transforming `String` into their **uppercase**-equivalents can easily be achieved by using the `String#toUpperCase` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase--)) function, analogously there is as `String#toLowerCase` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--)) method.

So you need to access each element of your array and then call the method on it:

```
// Print in uppercase
for (String name : names) {
    System.out.println(name.toUpperCase());
}
```

Or if your not familiar with the *enhanced-for* (foreach), a version using a regular *for* loop:

```
// Print in uppercase
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(names[i].toUpperCase());
}
```

---

### Full code with improvements

You also don't need to save all those variables, just store them inside your array. After that loop the array and transform the variables:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = new String[10];

    // Ask for names 10-times
    System.out.println("Please enter the ten names:");
    // Use try-with-resource for scanner-management
    try (Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + ": ");
            // Ensure that message is readable before
            // asking for input
            System.out.flush();

            // Store the input
            names[i] = userInput.nextLine();
        }
    }
    // Scanner is auto-closed due to try-with-resource

    // Print in lowercase
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name.toLowerCase());
    }

    // Print in uppercase
    for (String name : names) {
        System.out.println(name.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

---

### Locale

You can even set a `Locale` object since the upper- and lowercase may change in some languages. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase-java.util.Locale-) for some examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the values and uppercase them directly:

```
String firstName = userInput.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
// prints out the array in lowercase
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names10));
```

to:

```
// prints out the array in uppercase
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names10).toUpperCase());
```